# How to expose python web server using VPN

Tags: python, router, vpn, portforwarding, nat

I have just started learning web development using python. Now my web server is running fine on my development machine using port 80. However, when I wanted to visit my web from outside my LAN network I discovered that my ISP is blocking all ports. To over come this problem I used a free VPN provided by vpnbook.com (openVPN 2.4). When I use CanYouSeeMe.org site it tells me the port 80 is open, but I could not figure out how to connect to my web server. Neither the assigned IP 10.12.x.x:80 nor the remote IP 51.68.x.x:80 are working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm using flask framework on windows 10 . The following is the openVPN configuration downloaded from vpnbook.com:

```
client
dev tun3
proto tcp
remote 51.68.180.4 80
remote de4.vpnbook.com 80
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
fast-io
pull
route-delay 2
redirect-gateway
```

Answer (score 1):

Being a part of a VPN doesn't expose you to the world. In other words, once you are connected to it, it will not forward traffic from WWW to your machine on any port. It is just like replacing your home router with a much bigger one that you don't have the authority to define `forwarded ports`. The "worst" case scenario is that other machines in the same VPN will be able to reach you but that isn't usually the setup in public VPNs.

A solution you could use is SSH remote forwarding. You can read about it [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) (expect vertigo) but the gist is you connect to a cloud server you own with SSH and tell it to use the same SSH connection to forward connections coming to it to you (i.e. WWW -> cloud_machine:port -> your_machine:port). Because you own this cloud machine, you control its security and can open up listening ports to the world.

```
ssh -R 80:localhost:80 public.example.com
```

Then again, if you're willing to go this far, might as well deploy your app on that machine!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, The VPN provider (vpnbook.com) say they forward the ports 80, 443 and other ports, and the configuration I posted above is for forwarding the port 80, that's why CanYouSeeMe.org tells me the port 80 is open. Any advise?

Comment: Is using a VPN a possible way to expose my web server?

Comment: @froten In theory, yes. I've never done it and don't why using your vendor fails. You can begin to debug the issue using good old netcat (nc on most Linux distros), a useful network tool. Hook up another VM to the same VPN and talk between both machines using nc. One on listen, `nc -v -l 80` (needs root) and another try to connect `nc -v {ip} 80`.